# Manually Configure Unit test with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

I want to add `Unit test`(as like below) features with app. I know how to add it during creation of project as shown in picture

[image]

But my problem here is, my app is already in app store(and I missed above configuration while project creation). Now I want to add it my project, How can I add this? I know, `XCTest framework` should be add it to my project. Is any other important step to be done? Please give clear explanation with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your Project settings click on "Add Target..."

[image]

And from the sheet that pops down, choose the Test Target

[image]

Comment: Ya, thank you @Abizern. But replace second picture with IOS selection -> Other(left panel).